# Keycloak newly issued refresh token has same expiry as old refresh token

Tags: javascript, express, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I am using Keycloak for authentication. When I use the token API with grant_type ***refresh_token***, the resulting refresh token has the same expiry as the original refresh token. What should I do to get a refresh_token with an updated expiry time?
I have provided my settings below.

[keycloak-settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IECmR.png)